# Do I need a pronoun in this sentence

Tags: pronouns, sentence-structure

I wrote

> To make the process easier, the video frames are first converted to grayscale images, and then by applying a threshold **they** are converted to binary images.

Can I omit ***they*** or I should keep it?

Comment: There is no problem in dropping it. But it sounds better with *they*.

Comment: You can go as far as to remove the entire "they are converted" the second time and put a dash there.  "... and then, by applying a threshold, -- to binary images".

Answer (score 1):

To give the statement with utmost clarity, use *'they'*. Something tells me that you're writing an instructional or report based document. This type of documentation should convey maximum information with least amount of ambiguity and confusion. Using *'they'* will only give the sentence better clarity as to what you're "applying a threshold" to.